# How to spawn a form and not block main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I need to *spawn* a `Form` that can be used as usual but the main thread must continue doing whatever it is doing afterwards. When I try the 2 techniques below I can't use the form:

```
static class Program
{
    private static void spawnForm1()
    {
        new Form1().Show();
    }

    private static void spawnForm2()
    {
        // solved: use ShowDialog() instead of Show() here
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => { new Form1().Show(); });
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        spawnForm1();
        MessageBox.Show("main thread continues");
        // now anything can happen: background processing or start of main form
        // sleeping is just an example for how the form is unresponsive
        Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
    }
}
```

**So how can I spawn a simple Form and continue in main thread ?** It should respond just like the message box does.

*(I can't use `Application.Run(...);` and I can't use `ShowDialog()` if it would block the main thread, also: I'm sorry that I have not much reputation but this is not a noob question, I really need it to be spawned like I tried to explain)*

Comment: This sounds like a severe design issue to me. The main thread in *my* WinForm apps is always responsible for the UI and the other threads (thread pool and/or background worker) are responsible for the other, non-visual jobs. Your question seems to me that you want to do it just the other way around.

Comment: @UweKeim The main window is ran by application like always. But I need to spawn a window like I described it in both situation existing main window and also without it.

Comment: Start a window from the main thread and do a background processing in that window, instead.

Comment: You do know you can show multiple modeless windows in the same GUI thread without resorting to child threads (which would just end up freezing anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because there is no message loop. You simply must start a message loop for UI elements to function properly. That means at some point you must call `Application.Run` or `Form.ShowDialog`.

I see no reason why you cannot use the entry point thread for the UI and then create a worker thread to do whatever else it is you are wanting to happen while the UI is running.

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
  Task.Run(() => DoOtherStuff());
  Application.Run(new YourForm());
}
```

In a comment your wrote:

> The main window is ran by application like always. But I need to spawn
>   a window like I described it in both situation existing main window
>   and also without it.

I am assuming you mean that you want to run `Form` instances on both the entry point thread and a separate thread. My advise is to avoid doing this. It does not work very well. There are a lot of strange things that can happen. Rethink your design so that there is one and only one UI thread. Move any time consuming operations to a worker thread.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer only for the first paragraph. It helped me find the mistake. I forgot that every window needs a message loop.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a new thread to show the UI.  You're in the UI thread and it should be the one showing the form.  Spawn a new thread to do the non-UI work that you want to do instead:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Task.Run(()=>
        {
            //do non-UI work here
            Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
        });
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```